# Как добавить эти верхние штуки

Tags: html, css

нужно добавить эти верхние элементы

[image: картинка]

Comment: _"Как добавить эти верхние штуки"_ С огромной вероятность, это возможно реализовать написанием кода разметки и стилей.

Comment: С огромной вероятностью ваши комментарии бесполезны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё это делается псевдоэлементами after и before

```css
.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.element:before, .element:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
.element:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: calc(50% - 20px);
  border: 20px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 20px solid green;
  z-index: 10;
}
.element:after {
  top: -30px;
  left: calc(50% - 15px);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="element">

</div>
```